# boolean web service method always returns true even when it should not

Tags: vb.net, web-services, asmx

I have created a vb windows forms webservice in visual studio. I am having an issue where a boolean variable always returns true even when it should not. I am new to VB so it may just be a simple coding error but I just cannot figure it out.

Basically I have a sign in form, the user enters a username, from the form I pass the username to a function in the service called checkuser to see if the user exists in the DB. If the user does it exist it should go to another function to load existing data, if not it should call createuser function.

The variable should return true if user does exist and false if not. However when testing the program the variable always seems to return true even when I input a new username which does not exist.

Here is the form code(login form) which grabs the username and passes it to the checkUser function

```
Private Sub signInBtn_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles signInBtn.Click
    If signInNick.Text = "" Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter a user name")
        signInNick.Focus()
    Else
        signinName = signInNick.Text
        Dim check As Boolean
        check = service.checkUser(signinName)
        MessageBox.Show(check)
        If check = False Then
            main.Visible = True
            Me.Hide()
            main.tbxUserName.Text = signinName
            MessageBox.Show("User has been created")
        Else
            main.Visible = True
            Me.Hide()
            main.tbxUserName.Text = signinName
            MessageBox.Show("Thankyou for Signing In " + signinName)
        End If
    End If


End Sub
```

Here is the code for checkUser in the service

```
'Function to check if a user already exists in the database
<WebMethod()> _
Public Function checkUser(ByVal signinName As String) As Boolean
    Dim userToCheck As String
    Dim conn As New SqlConnection("Data Source=MARTIN-LAPTOP\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=musicPlaylist;Integrated Security=True")
    Dim sql As String = "SELECT userNick FROM Users WHERE userNick = ('" & signinName & "')"
    conn.Open()
    Dim objcmd As New SqlCommand(sql, conn)
    userToCheck = objcmd.ExecuteScalar()

    If userToCheck = signinName Then
        getExistingUserPLData(signinName)
        Return True
    Else
        createUser(signinName)
        Return False
    End If

End Function
```

The check variable in the form code always seems to return true and this causes the service function to jump to getExistingUserPLData which does not create a user if the user is new.

The strange thing is if I do this through the webservice web page at `http://localhost:50445/Service1.asmx`, type in a brand new user name and invoke checkUser it will return false if the user does not exist and true if user does exist but it will not work and only return true if done through the form client.

Update: the code provided in one of the answers

```
If String.Equals(userToCheck, signinName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) Then
```

appears to work somewhat, as it appears the program is jumpiong to the createUser function if a new username is typed into the login box, but it is giving me an error at the createUser function

> Voilation of primary key constraint, cannot insert duplicate key

here is the code for createUser

```
<WebMethod()> _
Public Function createUser(ByVal signinName As String) As String
    Dim conn As New SqlConnection("Data Source=MARTIN-LAPTOP\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=musicPlaylist;Integrated Security=True")
    Dim sql As String = "INSERT INTO Users (userNick) VALUES ('" & signinName & "')"
    conn.Open()
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(sql, conn)
    Dim newUserName As String = cmd.ExecuteScalar()
    conn.Close()
    Return newUserName
End Function
```

It throws the error at `Dim newUserName As String = cmd.ExecuteScalar()`

The column userNick is a primary key but I dont understand why it says cannot isert duplicate key when the user does not exist in the database at all, I have checked the DB and username does not already exist, is my code completely wrong?

thanks for your help

Comment: ASMX is a legacy technology, and should not be used for new development. WCF or ASP.NET Web API should be used for all new development of web service clients and servers. One hint: Microsoft has retired the [ASMX Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/asmxandxml/threads) on MSDN.

Comment: I have a boolean that returns False at the service and domain level, but as it bubbles up to the controller, it changes from False to True?!  VB.net world.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it is the cause, but your comparison of the username returned from the DB and the input value is case sensitive. When comparing strings, 99% of the time I prefer to use.

```
If String.Equals(userToCheck, signinName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) Then
  'True
Else
  'False
End If
```

Also, the line "signinName = signInNick.Text" is suspect as your code does not indicate what is happening here. Presumably it is a class scoped variable, however it could be a property that is not correctly implemented.

As a side, the line "If signInNick.Text = "" Then" would be better coded as:

```
If String.IsNullOrWhitespace(signInNick.Text) Then
```